# asp.net entity framework gridview update

Tags: asp.net

I can add and delete as a method. But if we look at the update part, there is no code sequence for this. How can I do this? Also, if there is anything I need to add, I would be glad if you could help.

```
    KullanicilarEntities vt = new KullanicilarEntities();

    public bool KullaniciEkle(KullaniciBilgileri kullanici)
    {
        

        vt.KullaniciBilgileri.Add(kullanici);
        vt.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }


    public List<KullaniciBilgileri> KullaniciBilgileriListele()
    {
        return vt.KullaniciBilgileri.ToList();
    }

    public bool KullaniciSil(KullaniciBilgileri kullanicici)
    {
        var silinecekkullanici = vt.KullaniciBilgileri.Where(p => p.KullaniciId == kullanicici.KullaniciId).SingleOrDefault();
        vt.KullaniciBilgileri.Remove(silinecekkullanici);
        vt.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }

    public bool GuncelleKullanici(KullaniciBilgileri kullanici)
    {
        //?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
    }
```

I can't write the update method, help me?

Comment: you should pull the particular entity using primary ley, update the properties and save it.

Comment: I couldn't. Can you help me?

Comment: what exactly is blocking you from implementing update?

Comment: Nothing is blocked, I need code, I can't write. I need a different command than the above.

Answer (score 0):

It's very similar to the remove

```
    public bool GuncelleKullanici(KullaniciBilgileri kullanici)
    {
        var silinecekkullanici = vt.KullaniciBilgileri.Where(p => p.KullaniciId == kullanicici.KullaniciId).SingleOrDefault();
        vt.KullaniciBilgileri.Update(silinecekkullanici); // This is the update our entity!
        vt.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }
```

Apologies, I've copied and pasted the code from your question so maybe the language isn't correct.

The main point is to replace `.remove` with `.update`

Comment: There is no update command, it does not appear in the program

Comment: There should be if you are using Entity Framework. What is `KullanicilarEntities` - is it a `DbContext`?

Comment: Also, what version of Entity Framework / ASP.NET are you using?

Comment: I use the most up-to-date version of everything.

Comment: @SEA It's Microsoft's entity framework? Does `KullanicilarEntities` inherit from `DbContext`? If it's does, it should have the `.Update` method

Comment: When I do Ctrl + space, No Update.

Comment: @SEA what is `KullanicilarEntities` ?? What does it inherit from? Can you update your question with the code for this class please.